# Correct syntax for wpdb prepare insert statement

Tags: sql, wordpress

I'm in the process of rewriting my SQL statements so they use prepare.

I have a problem with a SQL statement using prepare and INSERT INTO.

My code looks like this.

```
if ($count > 0)
{
    $query = "UPDATE $dbTable SET Distance = %d WHERE Date = %s AND UserID = %d";
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare($query, $formData, $today, $userID ));
}else{
    //$query = "INSERT INTO $dbTable ('Distance', 'Date', 'UserID') VALUES (%d,%s,%d)";
    //$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare($query, $formData, $today, $userID));

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO $dbTable ('Distance', 'Date', 'UserID') VALUES (%d,%s,%d)",$formData, $today, $userID);
    $wpdb->query($sql);
}
```

The UPDATE part workes fine but I get a Syntax Error in the INSERT part.
As you can see I've tried two different way to do execute the statement but both comes up with this error:

```
<div id="error"><p class="wpdberror"><strong>WordPress databasefejl:</strong> [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near &#039;&#039;Distance&#039;, &#039;Date&#039;, &#039;UserID&#039;) VALUES (65,&#039;2018-01-11&#039;,29)&#039; at line 1]<br /><code>INSERT INTO hfwp_Balance_Arm_Reach (&#039;Distance&#039;, &#039;Date&#039;, &#039;UserID&#039;) VALUES (65,&#039;2018-01-11&#039;,29)</code></p></div>
```

I can see from the output that the table name and values are translated correctly.

I don't know what the ' means but they have always been there including the old code.

Any ideas to the syntax error ??

Thanks

Flemming

Comment: Perhaps in the old code they were back ticks ` and you thought they were apostrophes ' because they look very similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use single quotes surrounding the column names.

Change this:

```
INSERT INTO $dbTable ('Distance', 'Date', 'UserID') VALUES (%d,%s,%d)
```

to this:

```
INSERT INTO $dbTable (Distance, Date, UserID) VALUES (%d,%s,%d)
```

With MySQL, you can use back ticks if you want, like this:

```
INSERT INTO $dbTable (`Distance`, `Date`, `UserID`) VALUES (%d,%s,%d)
```

Comment: That helped a lot.

I have always read ` as ' .

Thank you so much for the explanation.

It works now. :o)